# Is it possible to convert ForEach-Objects into Jobs?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which converts CSV data into XML. There is about 11k lines in the CSV file. The process in my script takes about 3-5 min to convert all of the lines into the xml string and the computer only uses 30% cpu.  Is there a more efficient way to do this? I have done some research on google and I keep reading about jobs but I don't understand how to use them or if this will work for me.

I have tested the affinity and priority and there is no change in performance when I set this to the highest levels.

The output is formatted the way I need for the system it is being loaded into. So ideally I do not want to change the output just the looping sections.

```
$OrderFile = "FileLocation.csv"
$OutputXML = "OutputFileLocation.xml"
$OrderData = Import-Csv -path $OrderFile

#Create a string template for the file and map fields for data.
$TemplateOuter = @'
<service_orders>$($xml)</service_orders>
'@

$TemplateCust = @'
<service_order><account_name></account_name><route_group></route_group><order_number>$($item.order_num)</order_number><delivery_type>$($item.delivery_type)</delivery_type><customer_code>$($item.customer_code)</customer_code><delivery_date>$($item.delivery_date)</delivery_date><cod>$($item.cod)</cod><service_time></service_time><note></note><line_items>$($items)</line_items></service_order>
'@

$TemplateItems = @'
<line_item><serial_number>$($item.sku)</serial_number><quantity>$($item.quantity)</quantity><amount>$($item.amount)</amount><description>$($item.description)</description><item_sequence></item_sequence><line_item_notes></line_item_notes><line_taxes>$($item.line_taxes)</line_taxes><line_amount></line_amount><category_name>$($item.category_name)</category_name><size_1>$($item.size_1)</size_1><size_2>$($item.size_2)</size_2><size_3>$($item.size_3)</size_3></line_item>
'@

#Loop through each of the orders and expand the order templates
$xml = $OrderData | Group-Object order_num -ov grp | ForEach-Object { 
            $items = foreach ($item in $_.Group) {
                $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($TemplateItems)
            }
        $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($TemplateCust)
        } | foreach {$_ -replace '&', '+'}

$xml = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($TemplateOuter)

#Create the XML File
$xml |Out-File $OutputXML

$OrdersXML = Get-Content $OutputXML
$Utf8NoBomEncoding  = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $false
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($OutputXML, $OrdersXML, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
```

My output comes out as expected for my needs but as I stated the CPU Usage is maxed at 30% with only 1 of 4 cores being used and the process takes about 3-5 min for 11k lines.

11/1/2019
So I i attempted the following

```
$xml = $OrderData | Group-Object order_num -ov grp
$xml= ForEach-Object { 
                        Start-Job -Name $_.Group -ScriptBlock {
                            $items = foreach ($item in $xml.Group) 
                            {
                                $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($TemplateItems)
                            }
                            $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($TemplateCust) | foreach {$_ -replace '&', '+'} 
                            } -ArgumentList $_.Group
               }
```

And I see a job and it states that hasmore data = true but when i receive the job there is nothing there....

Comment: You would like to use jobs to process several csv files or several lines inside one csv file parallel?

Comment: I would like to be able to process several lines inside of one csv file. Not sure what you mean by parallel. But for example my data has multiple orders and that order number will be repeated in multiple line. If somehow it can process multiple sets of orders at once I think this would be much faster.

Comment: If you change the flow to `foreach ($Order in ($OrderData | Group-Object order_num -ov grp)) { #Use Start-Jobs}` and then working with [Start-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-6) to run some processing in the background. But you have to write a job control to start for example 10 jobs at the same time, receive the result of finished jobs and remove them. Makes only sence if the processing of one csv line takes more than 10s.

Comment: @Patrick unfortunately I'm not an expert in PowerShell and the jobs part is completely foreign to me. Can you explain it a little more in depth?

Comment: Powershell 7 Preview does have foreach-object -parallel https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/

Answer (score 0):

Here an example how you could process data parallel with jobs in the background.

```
[System.Int16]$MaxRunningJobs = 10 #How many jobs should run at the same time
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$JobsToDo = @(1..20) #The input for the jobs --> data to process
[System.String[]]$JobOutput = @() #Output from the jobs

#This script will run inside the job and takes some input to process
[System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]$WorkToDo = {
    param
    (
        [System.Int16]$JobInput
    )

    #Do your work
    Start-Sleep -Seconds (Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 10)

    #Return output
    return ('Job ' + $JobInput + ' finished!')
}

#Process each job from the JobsToDo ArrayList and waits until every job is Completed & removed
while (($JobsToDo) -or (Get-Job))
{
    #Start jobs
    while (($JobsToDo) -and ((Get-Job -State Running).Count -lt $MaxRunningJobs))
    {
        #Start new job
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $WorkToDo -ArgumentList $JobsToDo

        #Remove started job from job list
        $JobsToDo.Remove($JobsToDo[0])
    }

    #Receive jobs
    foreach ($CompletedJob in (Get-Job -State Completed))
    {
        #Receive job output
        $JobOutput += Receive-Job -Job $CompletedJob

        #Remove job
        Remove-Job -Job $CompletedJob
    }
}

#Show job output
$JobOutput
```

Comment: This seems like it would work but i just don't understand how to use it. I am beginner in PowerShell and after spending a weekend reading about jobs and seeing multiple examples I cannot get this work.

Comment: Where do you struggle?

Comment: @ Patrick Attempting to Apply to apply the input into the jobs. In once test I did I opened up about 180 jobs in powershell and they all sat in memory in a running state but i was not able to get the output. So there are 3 parts to my struggle
1. Input: How do i pass my data once it has been grouped.
2. Scriptblock: How do i Convert my forearch loops
3. How can i get the outputs once the jobs are don and how can i pass those to a variable or file.